# How to pass variable from view page to base template

Tags: python, django

I am trying to login the user into his profile and need to pass the username to a navbar in a base template.
I have **base.html(base template)** and **index-client.html(body template)**. 
Now from login view, i would like to pass username value to base.html.

Code after user authentication is:

```
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('index-client.html')
```

I need to pass username to base.html i.e. a base template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{{ request.user }}` method is built in with Django, and you can use this in any template to access the User object.

If you want to display the user's name in the navbar you can use:

`{{ request.user.first_name|capfirst }} {{ request.user.last_name|capfirst }}`

*As can be seen this has the use of a template tag `|capfirst` to capitalise the first letter.*

Answer (score 0):

according to doc, `redirect` will accept

- A model: the model’s get_absolute_url() function will be called.
- A view name, possibly with arguments: reverse() will be used to reverse-resolve the name.
- An absolute or relative URL, which will be used as-is for the redirect location.

So redirect to specific view which render the base html. In html

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    {{ request.user.username }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Is there any way to pass a variable with a dynamic data (not user model) ?